# Ошибка при старте HTTP сервера (HttpListener)

Tags: c#, .net, windows, http

При попытке запустить HTTP сервер на C# через HttpListener выбивает следующую ошибку:

> Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу, так как этот файл занят другим процессом

Собственно, какие тайны может содержать HttpListener? Отладка показала, что ошибка именно на строчке localHttpServer.Start().

Если это важно, приложение представляет из себя COM-объект, и методы объекта вызываются из Delphi.

Разработка ведется под .NET v2.0.50727 (может быть поднят до v3.5).

```
using (var localHttpServer = new HttpListener())
        {
            localHttpServer.Prefixes.Add(Properties.Settings.Default.self_ip);
            localHttpServer.Start();
            ...
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подобная ошибка свидетельствует о том, что указанный TCP-порт (или префикс URL) уже занят другим процессом. Некоторые приложения могут занимать порты монопольно, наплевав на механизм совместного использования портов в WinHTTP. Единственные советы, которые можно дать:

- Выбрать другой порт и/или префикс URL
- Посмотреть с помощью netstat (или монитора ресурсов), какой процесс держит порт, и завершить его.

Comment: Действительно, проблема заключалась в порте.. Была идея, на счет этого, но почему то руки не дошли проверить. И netstat молчал.